# Apache defaulting to one virtual host instead of root folder of the other vhosts

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have 3 vhosts setup on xampp on my local windows machine. (see config below)

Whenever I direct my browser to stage.local or host.local I get redirected to dev.local which is the vhost I set up first, but shouldn't be the default vhost.

However, when I go to host.local/index.php the corrrect file is shown, somehow it's just the root directory that is messed up.
I'm not sure how this is possible or how to fix this.

The configuration seems correct, here is the full file:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#


<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@host.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/host.local/"
    ServerName host.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@stage.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/stage.local/"
    ServerName stage.local
    ErrorLog "logs/stage.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/stage.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev.local/"
    ServerName dev.local
    ErrorLog "logs/dev.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dev.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And httpd -S says this:

```
*:*                    is a NameVirtualHost
     default server host.local (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:29)
     port * namevhost host.local (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:29)
     port * namevhost stage.local (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:35)
     port * namevhost dev.local (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:43)
```

(some ssl stuff after)

and my hosts file has the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 host.local
127.0.0.1 stage.local
127.0.0.1 dev.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it's working. You need to define port for eg:-

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@host.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/host.local/"
    ServerName host.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@stage.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/stage.local/"
    ServerName stage.local
    ErrorLog "logs/stage.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/stage.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev.local/"
    ServerName dev.local
    ErrorLog "logs/dev.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dev.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```